# Is it possible to show videos from SharePoint Online in SharePoint 2013?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-online

I have a SP 2013 intranet and I want to display some videos in an iframe from SPO.

I try this ...

<iframe src='https://mytenant.sharepoint.com/:v:/s/VideoHub/xxx?e=xxx'>
                    
but I get 
mytenant.sharepoint.com refused to connect.
 
In my SP 2013 I go to Site Settings -  HTML Field Security
add mytenant.sharepoint.com but still no luck.

Thanks
P

Answer (score 0):

Do not use "Copy link" option to get the link to video from document library in SharePoint online.

Instead use below steps to get direct link:

1. Go to document library and select the file you for which you need direct link
2. Click on Open the details pane (i icon) from command bar (top right side)
3. Scroll down on properties pane and Copy direct link using the copy icon highlighted in below image:

[image]

Then use this in `src` property of `iframe`.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I get a console error ... Refused to frame 'https://mytenant.sharepoint.com/' because an ancestor violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "frame-ancestors 'self' teams.microsoft.com *.teams.microsoft.com *.skype.com *.teams.microsoft.us local.teams.office.com *.powerapps.com *.yammer.com *.officeapps.live.com *.office.com *.stream.azure-test.net *.microsoftstream.com *.dynamics.com *.microsoft.com securebroker.sharepointonline.com".

Comment: Can you try adding your tenant URL (`mytenant.sharepoint.com`) in HTML field security settings? Refer: https://bamboosolutions.com/blog/how-to-use-html-field-security-and-insert-iframes-into-sharepoint-2013-sites/

Comment: yes i've done that on a site level and also on the root site level just to be sure. still doesn't work. Error is ... Refused to frame 'https://mytenant.sharepoint.com/' because an ancestor violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "frame-ancestors 'self' teams.microsoft.com *.teams.microsoft.com *.skype.com *.teams.microsoft.us local.teams.office.com *.powerapps.com *.yammer.com *.officeapps.live.com *.office.com *.stream.azure-test.net *.microsoftstream.com *.dynamics.com *.microsoft.com securebroker.sharepointonline.com".